# Session not present when restarting browser

Tags: php, cookies

I login in my system and set a cookie this way:

```
setcookie("hello",true,time()+3600);
```

Then I look in the cookie manager of firefox and see that my cookie is set.

When I restart my browser and restart I see in the cookie manager that the cookie is ther but this code:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['hello'])){

            echo "yes"; exit;}
```

I don't see anything it redirects me to the login form.
Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things to try:

1. Explicity set the `path` attribute of `setcookie` to `/` so the cookies are available in the entire domain.
2. Instead of checking isset, try doing a `print_r` of `$_COOKIE` in an otherwise empty PHP file.
3. The `value` part of `setcookie` expects a string, not a boolean. I would imagine as it is right now `hello` is being set to `1`, although this wouldn't really matter on whether it is surviving a restart or not just thought I'd point it out.
4. Do you have your browser set to delete cookies on exit? In Firefox, for example, you can go to Tools -> Options -> Privacy and there is an option that says "Always clear my private data when I exit Firefox." If you have this set any cookies you have will be deleted when you close your browser.
5. Have you checked access to the cookie from PHP *prior* to the restart? You say you can see it in Cookie Manager before and after, but can you see it in PHP before or after?

Answer (score 3):

While a regular cookie, like your 'hello' cookie, will survive a browser restart, a session cookie will not.

It sound like you are using a session cookie for your login, so when you hit the page after a restart, you need to log in again.